Enrich csv file with data from GBQ
I have a table "phones" on GBQ with 300M rows with columns:
Color, Brand, RAM, Inches.
I also have a CSV file with 70,000 rows with information about phones: Color, Brand, RAM.
I need to extract data from the GBQ table for each row in the CSV file in different combinations.
The selection must be made by fields: Brand, Ram, Color.
I tried making a select for each entry in the csv using “or”:
here is part of the query:
SELECT * 
FROM `phones` 
WHERE ((COLOR LIKE 'Green' AND RAM LIKE '32' AND BRAND LIKE 'Apple') 
       OR (COLOR LIKE 'Red' AND RAM LIKE '64'))

But this way the query turned out to be very long, I could not transmit it via the GBQ API, I can divide the query into several queries, but I think the following solution should be better.
I tried to create another table from a csv file and join two tables:
SELECT *
FROM `phones` table1
LEFT JOIN `temp` AS table2
     ON ((table1.COLOR = table2.COLOR AND table1.RAM = table2.RAM AND table1.BRAND = table2.BRAND = 'Apple') 
         OR (table1.COLOR = table2.COLOR AND table1.RAM = table2.RAM));

But the query took a very long time to process (more than 30 minutes).
What other options might there be and what is the best way to deal with such big data (enrich csv using GBQ)?
